# Where can I get MDM9615 modem chipset datasheet?

Tags: datasheet, modem

I've been looking for this datasheet in the internet but I found nothing. I reaaly need this MDM9615 datasheet. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The MDM9615 appears to be a Qualcomm chip. Qualcomm does not provide datasheets to everyone. My guess is that they only provide datasheets to their customers and only after they have signed a Non Disclosure Agreement.

Usually you also cannot but such chips on Farnell, Digikey etc. The chips are only sold directly to Qualcomm's customers.

The reason for this might be that Qualcomm does not want to bother with requests from small customers and they want to control who can use their chips.

So unless you work for one of Qualcomm's customers I think you will find it almost impossible to acquire a datasheet.

Comment: Thank you @FakeMoustache for the answer. Do you know which modem chipset  datasheet 4G LTE can I get for free?